# Architecture of a director / executive / master / top-level application layer

Tags: c++, architecture

I have a collection of classes and functions which can interact with one another in rich and complex manners. Now I am devising an architecture for the *top-level* layer coordinating the interaction of these objects; if this were a word processor (it is not), I am now working on the `Document` class.

**How do you implement the top-level layer of your system?**

These are some important requirements:

- *Stand-alone*: this is the one thing that can stand on its own
- *Serializable*: it can be stored into a file and restored from a file
- *Extensible*: I anticipate adding new functionality to the system

These are the options I have considered:

**The [GOF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634988) [*Mediator Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)** used to *define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact [...] promotes loose coupling by by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently*.

The problem I see with mediator is that I would need to subclass every object from a base class capable of communicating with the Mediator. For example:

```
class Mediator;

class Colleague {
  public:
    Colleague(Mediator*);
    virtual ~Colleague() = default;
    virtual void Changed() {
        m_mediator->ColleagueChanged(this);
     }
  private:
    Mediator* m_mediator;
};
```

This alone makes me walk away from Mediator.

**The brute force blob class** where I simply define an object and all methods which I need on those objects.

```
class ApplicationBlob {
  public:
    ApplicationBlob() { }
    SaveTo(const char*);
    static ApplicationBlob ReadFrom(const char*);
    void DoFoo();
    void DoBar();
    // other application methods
  private:
    ClassOne m_cone;
    ClassTwo m_ctwo;
    ClassThree m_cthree;
    std::vector<ClassFour> m_cfours;
    std::map<ClassFive, ClassSix> m_cfive_to_csix_map;
    // other application variables
};
```

I am afraid of the Blob class because it seems that every time I need to add behaviour I will need to tag along more and more crap into it. But it may be good enough! I may be over-thinking this.

**The complete separation of data and methods**, where I isolate the state in a struc-like object (mostly public data) and add new functions taking a reference to such struct-like object. For example:

```
struct ApplicationBlob {
  ClassOne cone;
  ClassTwo ctwo;
  ClassThree cthree;
  std::vector<ClassFour> cfours;
  std::map<ClassFive, ClassSix> cfive_to_csix_map;
};

ApplicationBlob Read(const char*);
void Save(const ApplicationBlob&);
void Foo(const ApplicationBlob&);
void Bar(ApplicationBlob&);
```

While this approach looks exactly like the blob-class defined above, it allows me to physically separate responsibilities without having to recompile the entire thing everytime I add something. It is along the lines (not exactly, but in the same vein) of what Herb Sutter suggests with regards to [preferring non-member non-friends functions](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) (of course, *everyone* is a friend of a struct!).

I am stumped --- I don't want a monolith class, but I feel that at some point or another I need to bring everything together (the whole *state* of a complex system) and I cannot think of the best way to do it.

Please advise from your own experience (i.e., please tell me how do you do it in your application), literature references, or open source projects from where I can take some inspiration.